# Bio informatics: Pattern recognition in a DNA sequence

Tags: python

So, I am trying to make a python program that receives a DNA sequence like

> ATAAAAAGCGTAAGCATTGGCATCATTTGCAGCATACTCAAGCCATTTTTCAGCCAGCTCGGGCTCTTTT
> GTATATTTCGAGGCAACCCAGCCCTTCCCGCCAGCAAAAGGGGCGTATTCTTCTCCATTTGGCAATGTCG
> GAATGG

as input and I need it to recognize a pattern in the sequence let say "GGCAT" and I need the program to return "GGCAT has been found (so many times) in the sequence".
I've tried

```
print ("Pattern recognition system.")

option=input("Insert DNA sequence")

def PatternCount(Text, Pattern):
    count=0
    for i in range(0, len(text)-len(pattern)+1):
        if text[i:len(pattern+i)]== pattern:
            count=count+1

    return count
```

but I don't think this is the way to do it, saw it on a previous post but I get the error code multiple statements found while single statement smth.
Any ideas on how to make this happend?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

1. Use the `str.find()` method to find the pattern in the string
2. Replace the first occurrence of the pattern with empty string by using `str.replace(Pattern, '', 1)` method, (passing 1 as count makes it to replace only the first occurrence)
3. Keep doing this in a while loop until `find()` returns -1 and increment the `count` each time.

The code:

```
def PatternCount(Text, Pattern):
    count = 0
    while Text.find(Pattern) != -1:
        count = count + 1
        Text = Text.replace(Pattern, '', 1)

    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function,

I can see that

1. The name of the arguments you are passing **Text**, **Pattern** does not match with the one you are using inside **text**, **pattern**.
2. In your `if` condition `len(pattern+i)` has incorrect syntax. As pattern is a string and i is an integer. It should be `len(pattern)+i`

Please try this:

```
input_sequence = "ATAAAAAGCGTAAGCATTGGCATCATTTGCAGCATACTCAAGCCATTTTTCAGCCAGCTCGGGCTCTTTTGTATATTTCGAGGCAACCCAGCCCTTCCCGCCAGCAAAAGGGGCGTATTCTTCTCCATTTGGCAATGTCGGAATGG"
input_pattern = "GGCAT"

def PatternCount(sequence, pattern):
  count=0
  length_of_pattern = len(pattern)
  range_to_iterate = len(sequence)-length_of_pattern
  for i in range(0, range_to_iterate+1):
    if sequence[i:i+length_of_pattern]==pattern:
      count+=1
  return count

print (PatternCount(input_sequence, input_pattern))
```